# Django "__init__() keywords must be strings" error while running "runserver"

Tags: python, django

I just set up virtualenv to start django project. I installed everything fine.
when I issue "python manage.py runserver" it spits out this error. I tried all kind of django runserver error through out and no one seems to have this. Anyone have insight into it?

```
Validating models...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Command.inner_run of <django.contrib.staticfiles.management.commands.runserver.Command object at 0x1016bb0d0>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-hari/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 92, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-hari/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 280, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-hari/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.6.egg/django/core/management/validation.py", line 35, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-hari/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/loading.py", line 166, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-hari/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/loading.py", line 72, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-hari/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/loading.py", line 96, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-hari/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.6.egg/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-hari/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.6.egg/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 21, in <module>
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-hari/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.6.egg/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py", line 127, in <module>
    class ContentType(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-hari/lib/python2.6/site-packages/Django-1.5.4-py2.6.egg/django/db/models/base.py", line 97, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    __init__() keywords must be strings
```

Comment: Did you try looking at your model code?

Comment: Do you have a weird `Meta` class in one of your models?

Comment: I did not create any code. I was just following along a tutorial and right after installing django, i created a test project and hit "python  manage.py runserver" and gave this error. Is there a way I can modify the models code and rectify this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's [a known issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/18961). Django 1.5 [requires](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/install/#install-python) Python 2.6.5 or newer. You have an older version of Python installed on your computer. You need to [install a newer version of Python](http://www.python.org/getit/), for example Python 2.7.x.

Comment: Thanks everyone for taking time to looking into it